# How to apply instance of use() to all routes except those handed by app.use(express.static("dist"))?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I think I have resolved this issue in the process of writing it, basically the solution seems to be:

> Move the static file handler above the other instance of use()

Confirmation that this is an acceptable approach would be appreciated though and perhaps help others in a similar scenario.

**Desired Behaviour**

Apply a `use()` instance to all routes except those handled by:

```
app.use(express.static("dist"));
```

**Actual Behaviour**

`use()` is being applied to all routes, including those handled by:

```
app.use(express.static("dist"));
```

**Scenario**

For securing access to API's, I am using the model described in this Lynda.com tutorial:

[Node.js: Securing RESTful APIs](https://www.lynda.com/Node-js-tutorials/Node-js-Securing-RESTful-APIs/679638-2.html)

In pseudo code, the model is essentially comprised of:

- a global `use()` instance that checks if a jwt token has been sent
- if a token has been sent, if verifies the token
- it sets the `req.user` property to `undefined` if verification fails or a token wasn't sent
- otherwise, it sets the `req.user` property to the decoded jwt value if verification succeeds
- subsequent middleware performs conditional behaviour based on the value of `req.user`

This model is working well for all intents and purposes.

However, I recently added some console logging and can see that verification is being performed for both:

- api requests (desired behaviour)
- static files served via `app.use(express.static("dist"))` [per this convention](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) (undesired behaviour)

**Question**

How can I apply the verification `use()` instance to all routes, except those handled by `app.use(express.static("dist"))`.

**What I've Tried**

I think I have resolved this issue by moving section `2` of the code below above section `1`.

```
// 01.  verification use() called on all requests

app.use((req, res, next) => {

    // if jwt authorisation has been sent in headers, verify it
    if (req.headers && req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'JWT') {

        console.log("jwt verification sent, verifying...");

        try {
            // this is synchronous as it has no callback
            req.user = jsonwebtoken.verify(req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1], 'RESTFULAPIs');
            console.log("jwt verified, will return decoded value");
        } catch (err) {
            req.user = undefined;
            console.log("jwt verification failed, user will remain undefined: " + err);
        }

        // move to the next piece of middleware
        next();

    }
    // if jwt authorisation has not been sent in headers
    else {
        console.log("jwt verification not sent, leaving user as undefined");
        console.log(req.originalUrl);
        req.user = undefined;
        // move to the next piece of middleware
        next();
    }
});


// 02.  use() for serving static files
app.use(express.static("dist"));


// 03.  middleware to check if login has been verified
const api_login_required = (req, res, next) => {

    // if token verification was successful and the user property exists
    if (req.user) {
        // move to the next piece of middleware
        next();
    }
    // otherwise, return unauthorised user message
    else {
        res.json({ verification: 0 });
    }

}


// 04.  middleware called in route handlers
app.route("/api/:api_version/users/private_data")
    .get(api_login_required, api_users_private_data_get)
    .post(api_login_required, api_users_private_data_post);
```

Answer (score 0):

Middleware always controls the flow from to button in which order they wrote. Like

```
if (example 1)code like 
app.use((req,res, next)=>{// middleware 1; next()} )
app.get('/rot1', (req, res)=> res.status(200).send('route 1'));
app.get('/rot2', (req, res)=> res.status(200).send('route 2'));

In this case, middleware appears in both route1, route because of middleware set at the top of the route.

If (example 2)code like
app.use((req,res, next)=>{// middleware 1; next()} )
app.get('/rot1', (req, res)=> res.status(200).send('route 1'));
app.use((req,res, next)=>{// middleware 2; next()} )
app.get('/rot2', (req, res)=> res.status(200).send('route 2')); 

Here middleware1 applied in both route1 and route 2
But middleware2 applied only on route2.

But you can also define specific middleware for each route
function middleware1(req, res, next){
    next();
}
function middleware2(req, res, next){
    next();
}
app.get('/rot1', middleware1, (req, res)=> res.status(200).send('route 1'));
app.get('/rot2', middleware2, (req, res)=> res.status(200).send('route 2')); 

Here middleware1 only applied on route1 and middleware2 only applied on route2.
```

Maybe above explanation help you!!